# Mapping AltGr to left control

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb

I mapped my <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with the following command:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl
```

However, when displaying the bindings with

```
xmodmap -pke
```

I can see that the keycode is associated to

```
   keycode 108 = Control_R Control_R Control_R Control_R
```

**I would like to bind <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to LEFT Control.** Is it possible?

This is important for Emacs, otherwise I don't get the same input when pressing C-S-b with the original Left Control or with AltGr.

Comment: For those who might not know: 'AltGr' is the right hand 'Alt' key so labelled e.g. on a German keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maps to `Control_R` as that's how it's configured in `XKB` symbols for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. Changing the configuration should result in `Alt_R` being mapped to `Control_L`. Note that with this method, your custom configuration will be overwritten by any future upgrades of `xkeyboard-config` (at least that's the package that owns `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl` in Archlinux).
Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl`, scroll down to this section:

```
// right alt functions as another ctrl key
partial modifier_keys 
xkb_symbols "ralt_rctrl" {
    replace key <RALT> { type[Group1]    = "TWO_LEVEL",
                         symbols[Group1] = [ Control_R, Control_R ] };
    modifier_map Control { <RALT> }; 
};
```

and replace `Control_R` with `Control_L` so that it reads:

```
// right alt functions as another ctrl key
partial modifier_keys 
xkb_symbols "ralt_rctrl" {
    replace key <RALT> { type[Group1]    = "TWO_LEVEL",
                         symbols[Group1] = [ Control_L, Control_L ] };
    modifier_map Control { <RALT> }; 
};
```

save & restart X then run:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl
```

check with `xmodmap`:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep 108
keycode 108 = Control_L Control_L Control_L Control_L
```

To make it permanent add `setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl` to your session start-up.
Alternatively, add `ctrl:ralt_rctrl` to your `xorg.conf.d` config files, e.g.:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard    "yes"
    Driver             "evdev"
    Option             "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option             "XkbRules"  "evdev"
    Option             "XkbOptions" "ctrl:ralt_rctrl"
EndSection
```

Note to `Gnome` users: `Gnome` overrides `xorg` `XKB` options so one has to add `ctrl:ralt_rctrl` via `gsettings` (or `dconf-editor`):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:ralt_rctrl']"
```

Comment: I still get Control_R after a reboot:

    xmodmap -pke |grep 108
     keycode 108 = Control_R Control_R Control_R Control_R

Also a "No such schema 'org.gnome.desktop.input-sources'" error with gsettings.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome and a french layout.